# What's the best bound for T(n)=T(0.8n)+n, I suppose that's O(n), but I'm not sure of it

Tags: algorithm

I don't think I have fully understand recurrence in algorithm. 
Well, the n in the recurrence function can also be changed into n^2 or n^3. Are they just the same with the n case?
If applicable, what's the typical method of finding the **best bounds** of running time?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show what you have tried so far. If questions are too broad you might not get any answer.

Answer (score 0):

I also figured out that T(n) = T(0.8n) + n = O(n).

When solving recurrence relations, the most common way is by repeatly replacing functions by their expressions. S.t. T(n) = T(0.8n) + n = T(0.64n) + 0.8n + n = ... = (1 + 0.8 + 0.64 + 0.512 + ...)n. This is a typical geometric infinite progression. By applying basic calculus, we can easily get that T(n) = 5n = O(n).

When we change the n in the original expression by n^x and x is an arbitrary non-zero constants, we can always let some variable t = n^x, and T(t) is O(t), so n^x should be the same case with n. T(n^x) = O(n^x).

Comment: And O(n) should be a tight upper bound for function T.